# Could not complete execution for Gradle Test Executor Spring Boot 3.0

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, gradle, spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test

Whenever adding `spring-kafka-test` as a dependency I cannot run tests.

Tests start to fail for following reason:

```
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.TestSuiteExecutionException: Could not complete execution for Gradle Test Executor 1.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:64)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/launcher/TestExecutionListener
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    ...
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.platform.launcher.TestExecutionListener
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 50 more
```

This is what my gradle looks like:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile
import org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.bundling.BootJar

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.0.0"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.0"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.7.22"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.7.22"
    `maven-publish`
    `java-test-fixtures`
}

group = "com.example"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    api("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    api("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")

    api("com.auth0:java-jwt:4.2.1")
    api("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    api("io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging-jvm:3.0.4")

    api("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
    api("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    api("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb")
    api("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation")
    api("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    api("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    api("org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka")

    testFixturesApi("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testFixturesApi("org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-mockmvc")
    testFixturesApi("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
    testFixturesApi("org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test")
}

publishing {
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("maven") {
            groupId = project.group.toString()
            artifactId = project.name
            version = project.version.toString()

            from(components["java"])
        }
    }
}

tasks.getByName<BootJar>("bootJar") {
    enabled = false
}

tasks.getByName<Jar>("jar") {
    enabled = true
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

What am I missing in my configuration? What is the reason for this as I understand everything should be working fine.

Comment: Shouldn't those `testFixtureApi` be `testImplementation`? Not sure if the latter is added to the former and I don't think the regular test plugin sees it then.

Comment: [M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum) has exactly the same issue with `testImplementation`. `testFixtureApi` should not have any issues I did try with another project and it seems to work fine.

Comment: you need to have some runtime from spring - can not be all api() ;  spring-boot-starter-web and n not be all api() ;  spring-boot-starter-test must be implementation  or else manually add the junit5 dependencies

Comment: The Spring dependency management plugin might not be applying the Spring BOM to the test suite dependency configurations. Can you try adding `testFixturesApi(platform("<spring-bom gav>")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in `spring-kafka-test` version `3.0.0` which will be fixed in `3.0.1`.

For now, you can mitigate this by manually adding a test dependency on `org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher` in your gradle file.

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.9.1")
    testImplementation("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.9.1")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test:3.0.0")
}
```

See: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2490